# Keep Tabs on top of other Layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to use a `ListView` to show data from network. 
The data is loading properly from the source. But the problem is that if the data is loaded in `ListView` of one tab, the other tabs go away and I can't access them any more. I've attached screen shots to make it clear.

Here is the XML code of ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabView"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

This is mainfeed xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/feed_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"

     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

         <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
             android:id="@+id/profilePic"
             android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
             android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
         </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:textColorLink="@color/link" />

    <com.example.hissamyousaf.socialoid.FeedImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

TabWidget

The Tabwidget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: share code. merely screenshots wont help exactly

Comment: add this to your listView layout android:layout_above="@+id/tabView"

Comment: @AnswerDroid please check the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your FrameLayout like this

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
```